# How to get LastAccessed For SharePoint Site in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, auditing

I want do some analysis of a rather large Site Collection in SharePoint Online.

I want to figure out what has value and could be considered for migration vs old data that is not used.

I have been asked for **last accessed date** and **last modified date.**
This is because people may still be looking at data even if its old and has not been modified in a while.

Ideally I would like to report against every object in every site of the site collection.

Could anyone share a powershell script or other method they are using for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [ShareGate](https://sharegate.com/), as it's site reporting features are pretty good.

As for last accessed date, you may need to delve in to the [SharePoint audit logs](https://support.microsoft.com/office/view-audit-log-reports-b37c5869-1b47-4a82-a30d-ea20070fe527) to find this data.

**Update:** You can also use Microsoft Purview to inspect audit logs.

Comment: I am already using ShareGate and it does not support last accessed date OOTB. The O365 Audit Log is not practical for a large Site Collection and it only supports the last 6months.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the Audit Log is designed to deal with millions of records. I have updated my answer to include Microsoft Purview where you can manage retention policies e.g. the 6 month limit

Answer (score 0):

This article might help too:

[SPO Site LastContentModifiedDate vs LastItemModifiedDate vs LastItemUserModifiedDate vs Graph LastModifiedDateTime](https://vladilen.com/sharepoint/spo-site-lastcontentmodifieddate-vs-lastitemmodifieddate-vs-lastitemusermodifieddate/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below API to fetch the activity details of the file in array and get the first entry:

```
/_api/v2.0/drive/items('UniqueIdofthefile')/analytics/allTime?$expand=activities
```

Please let me know how you have handled for large datasets.